# files disapeared while moving

Tags: data-recovery

My files are disapeared while I move those files!

I moved my data from linux machine-ubuntu to my external HDD.
But I cannot find those files in both HDD(desktop nor external HDD).
I just click the directory and drag it.
(but...I didn't unmount external HDD and just pull out usb.)

Those data are very important, so I want to recover it (or find it).
What can I do for it?

Comment: I was moving a lot of files, and I found it took 5 minutes(twas only 11gig) for the cp,pletion, even while the popup bar was done, maybe you should wait until the indicator stops flashing

Comment: Thank you for your reply. popup bar was done at that time, but I already eject external HDD without no more waiting, and I cannot find my files on my desktop nor external HDD. Can I recover it?  T_T)/

Comment: ***ALWAYS*** unmount a device before you remove it from the system. ***ALWAYS***. Otherwise you can damage the device and/or suffer data loss like you did here. I'm not sure you can recover it, so I am not going to post an answer here.

Comment: Well i moved about 100GiB of data before formatting and about 50MB of data was lost for sure, and i would not have minded it but the data was so important that i barely passed in my exams, and saved my neck from a teacher by submitting a kind of fake project. I removed my external hdd safely but the awesome udisks bug would remount it so kindly in one sec that i'm not able to remove my drive. Please correct the bug **before my cat dies**